# Howe duality vs first fundamental theorem in invariant theory

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory

I'm working on Howe duality, and R. Howe proved that the Howe duality of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is equivalent to the first fundamental theorem (FFT) in invariant theory. So, Howe duality gives a representation-theoretic interpretation of FFT, but I don't know why we need this interpretation, what is the benefit of it?  Why Howe duality is important?

Comment: Well, the fact that there are other instances of Howe duality beyond this one from classical invariant theory is already enough motivation for studying the general concept, no?

Comment: @SamHopkins yes, but I mean what the benefit? Does this interpretation helps us understanding deeper about rep or invariant theory?